# Strange behaviour of SPI lines on STM32

Tags: stm32, spi, cmsis

I am learning to develop drivers for Cortex M using CMSIS framework. In the past I have written SPI drivers for transmitting data to peripherals. Now I need to write code to receive on SPI line, however I have very strange behaviour in my code.

Setup: **STM32F303VCT6** on discovery board. **MCP23S17** 16-bit port expander. Port A of port expander is connected to 8 leds and the port B is connected to 8 dip switches. My goal is to read the status of switches on port B and glow leds on port A accordingly.

Code :

```
#include "stm32f3xx.h"                  // Device header

#define CS_LOW (GPIOB->ODR &=~(1<<12))
#define CS_HI (GPIOB->ODR |= 1<<12)


#define SLAV_WR         0X40
#define SLAV_RD         0X41
#define IO_A            0x09
#define IO_B            0X19
#define IODIR_A         0X00
#define IODIR_B         0X10    
#define IPOL_A          0x01
#define IPOL_B          0X11
#define INTCON_A        0X05
#define INTCON_B        0X15
#define GPINTEN_A       0X02
#define GPINTEN_B       0X12



void SPI2_init();
void SPI_writebyte(uint8_t data);
void MCP23S17_setup(void);

uint8_t SPI_rdwr(int data);

volatile uint8_t f;

int main()
{
    volatile uint8_t x;
    
    SPI2_init();
    CS_HI;
    MCP23S17_setup();
    
    
    while(1)
    {
        //read IO_B
        CS_LOW;
        
        SPI_rdwr(SLAV_RD);
        SPI_rdwr(IO_B);
        x = SPI_rdwr(0x00);             //dummy byte
        
        CS_HI;
        
    //************************************************
        //write to IO_A
        CS_LOW;
        
        SPI_writebyte(SLAV_WR);
        SPI_writebyte(IO_A);
        SPI_writebyte(x);
        
        CS_HI;

        
    }
}






uint8_t SPI_rdwr(int data)
{
    while(!(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
    *(__IO uint8_t *)&SPI2->DR = data;
    
    
    while(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_BSY);

    
    while(!(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));           //wait till RX buffer in not empty
    f = *(__IO uint8_t *)&SPI2->DR;
    return f;
}




void SPI_writebyte(uint8_t data)
{
    while(!(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
    *(__IO uint8_t *)&SPI2->DR = data;
    
    while(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_BSY);
}




void SPI2_init()
{
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_SPI2EN;
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOBEN;
    
    GPIOB->MODER &=~(3<<24 | 3<<26 | 3<<28 | 3<<30);
    GPIOB->MODER |= 1<<24 | 2<<26 | 2<<28 | 2<<30;
    
    GPIOB->AFR[1] &=~(0xF<<20 | 0xF<<24 | 0xF<<28);
    GPIOB->AFR[1] |= 5<<20 | 5<<24 | 5<<28;
    
    SPI2->CR1 &=~(SPI_CR1_SPE);
    SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_MSTR | SPI_CR1_SSI | SPI_CR1_SSM;
    SPI2->CR1 |= 1<<3;
    //SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR2_RXNEIE;
    SPI2->CR2 |= SPI_CR2_FRXTH;
    
    SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
    
}


void MCP23S17_setup(void)
{

    //**********************************************************************    
    CS_LOW;
    
    SPI_writebyte(SLAV_WR);
    SPI_writebyte(0x0A);            //access IOCON register
    SPI_writebyte(0x98);            //unpair GPIO A an B for 8 bit mode
        
    CS_HI;
//**********************************************************************
    
    CS_LOW;
    
    SPI_writebyte(SLAV_WR);
    SPI_writebyte(IODIR_A);     //0x00
    SPI_writebyte(0x00);                //set whole GPIO Port A as output
        
    CS_HI;
//**********************************************************************

    CS_LOW;
        
    SPI_writebyte(SLAV_WR);
    SPI_writebyte(IO_A);
    SPI_writebyte(0x00);            //set output of Port A to 0 at start
        
    CS_HI;

//**********************************************************************

    CS_LOW;
    SPI_writebyte(SLAV_WR);
    SPI_writebyte(IODIR_B);
    SPI_writebyte(0xFF);                //set whole GPIO Port B as input 
    
    CS_HI;
//**********************************************************************

    CS_LOW;
    SPI_writebyte(SLAV_WR);
    SPI_writebyte(IPOL_B);
    SPI_writebyte(0xFF);                    //read polarity of signals as opposite on PortB(since they are pulled high by ext resistor)
    CS_HI;

}
```

This code works and does the job. Here are the waveforms on logic analyser:

[image]

My issue though, is this: I was expecting to write a single function SPIrdwr() so that even if I have to just transmit, I would write to data register and return to main. However that doesn't seem to work. That's why I have the SPI_writebyte() function used all over the place. What could be the possible reason for this?

Furthermore, in the while loop inside main() function, if I use the SPI_writebyte() function while requesting read operation on port B of MCP23S17, the code ceases to work. Same thing while writing to port A, if I use the SPIrdwr() instead of SPI_writebyte(), I don't get the desired result.

Even when I make the above mentioned changes, the output of the logic analyser doesn't change, except for the SPI controller writing 0x7F (even though 0x13 is produced on MISO line).

Could someone explain the strange behaviour?

Comment: The read and write have different addresses (command codes), so I don't understand why you would think that you could combine them.

Comment: @Mattman944 if you look at my SPI_rdwr() function, I am transmitting data first. And the fact that I do get output waveforms for writing to IO_A implies it's not getting stuck after a rdwr call.